# Generate one single file for each entry with Vite

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vite

Basically what I need is generate one single file that contain all vendors and dependencies for each entry..

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [ react() ],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        popup: path.resolve(pagesDirectory, 'popup', 'index.html'),
        background: path.resolve(pagesDirectory, 'background', 'index.ts'),
        content_script: path.resolve(pagesDirectory, 'content_script', 'ContentScript.tsx')
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'src/pages/[name]/index.js',
        chunkFileNames: isDevelopment ? 'assets/js/[name].js' : 'assets/js/[name].[hash].js',
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          const { dir, name: _name } = path.parse(assetInfo.name);
          const assetFolder = getLastElement(dir.split('/'));
          const name = assetFolder + firstUpperCase(_name);
          return `assets/[ext]/${name}.chunk.[ext]`;
        }
      }
    }
  }})
```

In this case.. will be one file for **popup**, **background** and **content_script**

Here is one example of **ContentScript.tsx** file...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import Badge from './badge';

function init(query: string) {
  const appContainer = document.querySelector('#search') as HTMLElement;
  if (!appContainer) {
    throw new Error('Can not find AppContainer');
  }

  const rootElement = document.createElement('div');
  rootElement.setAttribute('id', 'web-answer-content-script');
  appContainer.insertBefore(rootElement, appContainer.firstChild);

  const root = createRoot(rootElement, {});
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Badge query={query} />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}

const searchParameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (searchParameters.has('q')) {
  const query = searchParameters.get('q');
  init(query);
}

import MessageSender = chrome.runtime.MessageSender;
function handleMessageReceived(message: string, sender: MessageSender) {
  console.log('>>> MESSAGE RECEIVED', message, sender);
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessageReceived);
```

With this configuration I'm getting this..

[image]

and my **content_scripts/index.js** ..

```
import { j as n, c as a, r as c } from '../../../assets/jsx-dev-runtime.a077470a.js';
// ..rest of the code...
```

As you can see.. I don't want this `import...` statement ..

Comment: Try the legacy plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-legacy